# Scripting a specific Canvas clearRect implementation?

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, canvas

scripting help needed for this specific URL: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/4hfkb/6/

Simply, I am trying to script a clearCanvas drawing feature via a clearRect function. Can anyone let me know how to do this?

What I think are the snippets needed to script this are as follows, but I do not know how the JavaScript area gets resolved within the web page in order to clear Canvas1:

HTML:

```
<a href="#canvas1">clearCanvas</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
function clearCanvas() {            
             context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
         }
```

Any scripting solution that properly "runs" on the JSFIDDLE site - and clears the drawing on the Canvas area - would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Add the below function within `Sketch` main function.

```
Sketch.prototype.clear = function () {
  this.actions = [];
  return this.redraw();
};
```

To clear `canvas`

```
$("#canvas").sketch("clear");
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/oLtoufog/)**

Comment: Nice one Omar! plus 1

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking to clear any canvas, you need to get the canvas and then get the 2d context of that canvas before you call ClearRect:

```
function clearCanvas() {  
    var canvas = $('#canvas1')[0];
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

In that specific FIDDLE, I was using the sketch.js plugin to allow drawing on the cnavas. The plugin provides an eraser function that requires no script (See http://intridea.github.io/sketch.js/). Just add this markup:

```
<div class="tools">
    <a href="#canvas1" data-tool="marker" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Marker</a>
    <a href="#canvas1" data-tool="eraser" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Eraser</a>
</div>
<canvas id="canvas1" ></canvas>
```

Click on the marker button to draw and click on the Eraser button to clear.

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/4hfkb/17/)**

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for these development efforts on clearing the canvas area! These solutions, upon actual device testing on Apple ios7, seem to not function 100%. While these solutions effectively erase the canvas, they do not function properly with the drawing history. This new FIDDLE comes closer to a preferred solution because of recognizing the issue with the drawing history:

http://jsfiddle.net/4hfkb/18/

The difference is in the javascript at the bottom/end of existing script. Any way that the drawing history can be taken into account to arrive at a 100% solution? Would additional listeners be needed to fully compensate for the clearing feature? Otherwise, this very cool sketcher has great ios7 potential. Would like to see this 100% functionality, if possible, and keep up the great problem solving!

```
[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/4hfkb/18/
```